# case statement instead of multiple selects

Tags: sql, select, case

I have several statements of code below, and I am trying to figure out a way to make this much more simple and easier. I would assume that a CASE statement would be best but after a few days of trial and error, I have been unable to figure out how to do so. Any and all help and/or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

```
select Count(lcs.statename)  as [Name 1]
   FROM hsi.itemlc as ilc
   LEFT JOIN hsi.lcstate as lcs on lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
   where lcs.statename = 'Follow Up'
   AND lcnum = '412'
   AND status = '0'
select Count(lcs.statename)  as [Name 2]
   FROM hsi.itemlc as ilc
   LEFT JOIN hsi.lcstate as lcs on lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
   where lcs.statename = 'Initial Review'
   AND lcnum = '412'
   AND status = '0'
select Count(lcs.statename)  as [Name 3]
   FROM hsi.itemlc as ilc
   LEFT JOIN hsi.lcstate as lcs on lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
   where lcs.statename = 'Execution'
   AND lcnum = '412'
   AND status = '0'
select Count(lcs.statename)  as [Name 4]
   FROM hsi.itemlc as ilc
   LEFT JOIN hsi.lcstate as lcs on lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
   where lcs.statename = 'Holdback'
   AND lcnum = '412'
   AND status = '0'
```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... details of syntax are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN lcs.statename = 'Follow Up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Name 1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN lcs.statename = 'Initial Review' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Name 2],
    SUM(CASE WHEN lcs.statename = 'Execution' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Name 3],
    SUM(CASE WHEN lcs.statename = 'Holdback' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Name 4]
FROM hsi.itemlc as ilc
LEFT JOIN hsi.lcstate as lcs on lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
WHERE lcnum = '412'
AND status = '0'
```

Comment: That works perfectly... couple days down the drain but thanks a million

Comment: Now what if I were to add other columns to this... I am getting a "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'hsi.itemlc.itemnum' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Error when trying to add 

    ilc.itemnum as [test], directly after SELECT

Comment: @John You'll have to GROUP BY that column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a SUM() and a CASE:

```
SELECT
      SUM(CASE WHEN lcs.statename = 'Follow Up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as [Name 1],
      SUM(CASE WHEN lcs.statename = 'Initial Review' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as [Name 2],
      ...
   FROM hsi.itemlc as ilc
   LEFT JOIN hsi.lcstate as lcs on lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
   WHERE lcnum = '412' AND status = '0';
```

Or if you can read multiple rows, you could use a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT lcs.statename, COUNT(*) AS num
    FROM hsi.itemlc as ilc
    LEFT JOIN hsi.lcstate as lcs on lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
    WHERE lcnum = '412' AND status = '0'
    GROUP BY lcs.statename;
```

which will give you something like

```
Follow Up        25
Initial Review   17
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE statements with the `SUM()` function, as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN lcs.statename = 'Follow Up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as [Name 1],
       SUM(CASE WHEN lcs.statename = 'Initial Review' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as [Name 2],
       SUM(CASE WHEN lcs.statename = 'Execution' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as [Name 3],
       SUM(CASE WHEN lcs.statename = 'Holdback' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as [Name 4]
FROM hsi.itemlc as ilc
LEFT JOIN hsi.lcstate as lcs on lcs.statenum = ilc.statenum
WHERE lcnum = '412'
  AND status = '0'
```

Which result in conditional counts of each state name.